# Как сделать релизную сборку программы, написанной на C# в Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code

Программа рабочая, хочу сделать сборку, создать установщик (в этом опыт есть) и дальше опубликовать на SourceForge и т. п. До этого писал программы на Python, компилировал и опубликовывал программы, а вот как это сделать с C# не знаю. Помогите!

Comment: Чтобы создавать установщики, в студии для этого есть специальный тип проекта

Comment: А мне сначало нужно сделать сборку основного проекта

Comment: Это? https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrjrF.png ???